# Array processing with JSON in Delphi 7

Tags: arrays, json, delphi

I have a response coming to me that looks like this:

```
{
    "successful": true,
    "responseMessage": "OK",
    "responseCode": 2000,
    "messages": [
        {
            "messageId": "da86ede3-83de-4080-9c20-e8a335a7ac25",
            "messageType": "MessageComposeSendNotification",
            "queuedDateTime": 1402092032000,
            "processAttemptCount": 0,
            "processed": false
        },
        {
            "messageId": "382556a3-0654-4a1c-9b54-8393097d9ec9",
            "messageType": "RecordFileImport",
            "queuedDateTime": 1410811005000,
            "processAttemptCount": 1,
            "processed": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I can access the first three fields fine by just doing a `js.Field['successful'].value` call or the other field names. I now need to access the `Messages` array. What I want to do is step through each item in `Messages`. If the `MessageType` is `"RecordFileImport"` I want to save the `MessageID` to a stringlist.

Right now I can't access `Messages`. I assume I need to create a new `tlkJSONObject` or possibly a `tlkJSONList` to access its contents but I can't seem to instantiate that object and don't know how to navigate through the items.

I'm using Delphi 7 and LkJSON v1.07.

Answer (score 6):

The `Field[]` property returns a `TlkJSONbase` object.  You would use that property to access all fields, even arrays.  When accessing the `messages` field, instead of using its `Value` property, you would use its `Count` and `Child[]` properties.  For example:

```
var
  js: TlkJSONbase;
  Messages: TlkJSONbase;
  MessageIDs: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  ...
  js := ...;
  ...
  messages := js.Field['messages'];
  MessageIDs := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for I := 0 to messages.Count-1 do
    begin
      if VarToStr(messages.Child[I].Field['messageType'].Value) = 'RecordFileImport' then
        MessageIDs.Add(VarToStr(messages.Child[I].Field['messageId'].Value));
    end;
    ...
  finally
    MessageIDs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can type-cast the `messages` field to `TlkJSONlist` and use its `ForEach()` method.  For example:

```
procedure TMyClass.GetMessageIDs(ElName: string; Elem: TlkJSONbase; data: pointer; var Continue: Boolean);
begin
  if VarToStr(Elem.Field['messageType'].Value) = 'RecordFileImport' then
    TStringList(data).Add(VarToStr(Elem.Field['messageId'].Value));
end;

procedure TMyClass.ProcessJson;
var
  js: TlkJSONbase;
  Messages: TlkJSONlist;
  MessageIDs: TStringList;
begin
  ...
  js := ...;
  ...
  messages := js.Field['messages'] as TlkJSONlist;
  MessageIDs := TStringList.Create;
  try
    messages.ForEach(GetMessageIDs, MessageIDs);
    ...
  finally
    MessageIDs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Oddly enough I'm having difficulty with something that would appear much simpler. Another call returns a message like this:              `{
    "successful": true,
    "responseMessage": "OK",
    "responseCode": 2000,
    "summary": {
        "messageId": "382556a3-0654-4a1c-9b54-8393097d9ec9",
        "messageType": "RecordFileImport",
        "queuedDateTime": 1410811005000,
        "processAttemptCount": 2,
        "processed": false
    },
    "message": {
        "sentByName": "TestUser",
        "sentByUserId": "user",
        "record": "Test"
    }
}`  I'm having trouble pulling record

Comment: What is the problem? `js.Field['messages']` would return `nil`, and `js.Field['summary']` would return a `TlkJSONbase`, and then you would read its `Field['messageId']` and `Field['messageType']` values as needed.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what the problem is. It isn't reading the record that is the problem. It is failing so when I look at record it doesn't exist. The problem is when I make the call some of the records are huge. These are entire files I'm pulling down. I think my code is timing out. One of the files is 1.5 characters long. I need to figure out how to get my TIDHTTP to wait for this and I don't think my string variable will be big enough to contain the response. sResponse := HTTP1.Post(sAddress, JsonToSend); Would I need to use a stream to extract that file?

Comment: By design, `TIdHTTP` already waits for the entire response to be received, unless a timeout you specify in the `ReadTimeout` property is exceeded (in which case, an exception is raised). By default, everything in Indy uses an infinite timeout.  So that is not the problem, something else is going on.

Comment: I made that assumption because it is trapped in RaiseConnClosedGracefully. The comment in there for client says the server side of this connection has disconnected normally but your client has attempted to read or write to the connection. You should trap this error.... This is the call stack: TIdIOHandler.RaiseConnClosedGracefully
TIdIOHandlerStack.CheckForDisconnect(True,True)
TIdIOHandler.ReadBytes(..very long sequence..
TIdIOHandler.ReadStream($69ECFB0,-1,True)
TIdCustomHTTP.ReadResult($756836C,$75685B4)
TIdHTTPProtocol.ProcessResponse((...))
TIdCustomHTTP.DoRequest(
TIdCustomHTTP.Post(

Comment: That is perfectly normal if the response data is terminated by a socket closure, rather than via logic based on the `Content-Length`, `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, or `Content-Type: multipart/...` response header.  If the server indicates the termination condition is a socket closure, `TIdHTTP` handles that internally for you. Otherwise, the exception is raised into your code as a real error since the response is incomplete. The fact that `ReadResult()` is calling `ReadStream(...,-1,True)` means that a socket closure is the actual termination condition, so don't worry about it...

Comment: ... and `Post()` will return whatever data was actually received until the socket closure occurs.

Comment: First method don`t work for object. http://pastebin.com/nf147Ekp - prints empty lines

Comment: @Artem: The code I showed in my answer works fine for the JSON in the question, I tested and verified it. In your example, I don't know if this is a bug in LkJSON or not (if not, then it is certainly not intuitive), but `vJsonObj.Child[i]` is returning a `TlkJSONobjectmethod` instead of a `TlkJSONobject`, so you have to typecast the `Child[]` value to `TlkJSONobjectmethod` and use its `ObjValue` property to get the real `TlkJSONobject`, then accessing `Field['name']` from that will work correctly: `writeln(VarToStr((vJsonObj.Child[i] as TlkJSONobjectmethod).ObjValue.Field['name'].Value));`